# Does Uber Rides api support Scheduling a ride?

Tags: uber-api

I don't see an api to schedule an Uber ride in the future. Has anyone been able to determine if this is possible? @Uber is this in your pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

At this time, the Uber API does not support scheduling a ride in the future. You can request a ride with the `POST /v1/requests` endpoint or create a ride reminder with the `POST /v1/reminders` endpoint.

There are tutorials for both of these options:

- [Ride request tutorial](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/tutorials-rides-api)
- [Ride reminders tutorial](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/tutorial-ride-reminders)